# this.responseData xhr.responseXML

Tags: javascript, android, xml, httpclient, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to get remote data from rss feeds (xml file)

what I found that

```
Ti.API.info("response "+xhr.responseData);
```

return all the information on the xml file (as blob object) but

```
Ti.API.info("response "+xhr.responseXML);
```

returns null

actually I want it to be xml to be easy to deal with the information, so how can I convert from blob object to XML or what may cause xhr.responseXML to return null ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that your responseData is XML valid? If it's not, that could be one of the reasons that Titanium isn't automatically parsing the XML data in the XHR object itself.

You can always run:

```
var data = Ti.XML.parseString(result);
```

On the data itself, if you get an error, you know that you're doing something wrong.